# Create Pods using Rancher with Terraform

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, rancher

I created this simple Terraform script with Rancher to create namespace in imported Kubernetes cluster:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    rancher2 = {
      source = "rancher/rancher2"
      version = "1.24.1"
    }
  }
}

provider "rancher2" {
  api_url   = "https://192.168.1.128/v3"
  token_key = "token-n4fxx:4qcgctvph7qh2sdnn762zpzg889rgw8xpd2nvcnpnr4v4wpb9zljtd"
  insecure = true
}

resource "rancher2_namespace" "zone-1" {
  name = "zone-1"
  project_id = "c-m-xmhbjzdt:p-sd86v"
  description = "zone-1 namespace"
  resource_quota {
    limit {
      limits_cpu = "100m"
      limits_memory = "100Mi"
      requests_storage = "1Gi"
    }
  }
  container_resource_limit {
    limits_cpu = "20m"
    limits_memory = "20Mi"
    requests_cpu = "1m"
    requests_memory = "1Mi"
  }
}
```

The question is how I can create Pods into the Kubernetes cluster using again Terraform script?

Answer (score 1):

Terraform offers the [Kubernetes Provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs) which allows you to create all kind of Kubernetes objects.

To quote the [documentation of the "kubernetes_pod"-resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/pod#example-usage):

```
resource "kubernetes_pod" "test" {
metadata {
  name = "terraform-example"
}

spec {
  container {
    image = "nginx:1.21.6"
    name  = "example"

    env {
      name  = "environment"
      value = "test"
    }

    port {
      container_port = 80
    } 

    liveness_probe {
      http_get {
        path = "/"
        port = 80

        http_header {
          name  = "X-Custom-Header"
          value = "Awesome"
        }
      }

      initial_delay_seconds = 3
      period_seconds        = 3
    }
  }

  dns_config {
    nameservers = ["1.1.1.1", "8.8.8.8", "9.9.9.9"]
    searches    = ["example.com"]

    option {
      name  = "ndots"
      value = 1
    }

    option {
      name = "use-vc"
    }
  }

  dns_policy = "None"
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks, I was that but several questions are not clear: 1. I need to create a service account  and use user/pass or token in order to connect Terraform script with native Kubernetes cluster? Is there other way? 2. How to apply Helm chart from a directory?

Comment: The provider also offers service accounts: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/service_account

Comment: You can also just refer to the kubeconfig (if existing) and the provider will do the authentication: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs#example-usage

Comment: Can you share more about `service accounts` creation with kubernetes provider?